# Why "npm run lint" is pointing to .eslintrc in parent folder not current?

Tags: node.js, eslint

```
cd ~me/olc/componment1/src
```

there's a .eslintrc.

```
npm install
```

node_modules now contains eslint-config-airbnb-base as our .eslintrc extends from airbnb-base.

```
npm run lint
```

it failed, saying "was referenced from the config file ~me/olc/.eslintrc".

So how come it's not using the .eslintrc from current folder, but from ../../.eslintrc ?
How to fix this pls ?

Answer (score 3):

By default, ESLint will look for configuration files in all parent folders up to the root directory.
ESLint will stop looking in parent folders once it finds a configuration with "root": true.
https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#cascading-and-hierarchy

BTW why ppl are giving negative points instead of helping ? any reason my question is not clear enough ?